# Get a folder name that contains and string and then open it?

Tags: vb.net

This is the best i could do :

```
If fileName.Contains("hi")
```

**But what i want to do it .**

Open a folder : C:\Documents and Settings\5416339.5416339-PC\Application Data\ and navigate into a folder that contains "hi" and then modify a file pref.js in it. (100% this file is in that folder and there is only one such folder)

Can you guys do this for me ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) and [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) classes.

Both have methods that will list the contained directories and files - this should give you enough to find a directory called `hi`.

As for modifying the file, without knowing more about this file and how you want to modify it, I can't help.

Comment: @user539493 - The information you added doesn't help any more.